# Tomcat unknown classloader with java 11

Tags: java, tomcat

I changed the java of my project from java 8 to java 11 and
when tomcat starts it deploys .war files i have specified,
however with Java 11 it failed to deploy them , the tomcat is version 5.5
here is the log from Catalina

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.36
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader setClassPath
INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader setClassPath
INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive axis2.war
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:03 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader setClassPath
INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive MicroClient.war
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader setClassPath
INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
Sep 02, 2020 10:09:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Any suggestions where the problem can be?

Comment: Those logs are at INFO, which don't typically indicate a problem, which is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 was last updated 8 years ago. Chances are it will not work flawlessly with current Java versions, especially since Java 9 significantly tweaked how class loading worked by introducing modules and Tomcat quite heavily plays with classloading.

Comment: Suggestion: the problem is your assumption that such an upgrade could work out of the box.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the flawed premise that using a much newer java for an outdated version of apache is a supported configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 5.5 was last released 2012-10-09, e.g. 8 years ago, just after its announced [end-of-life](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-55-eol.html) in September 2012.

Java 11 was [released in September 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history), *6 years after* Tomcat 5.5 went to unmaintained state.

> Any suggestion where the problem can be?

You do the math on release dates above. Upgrade!